# On OSX Yosemite, under JDK 1.8.0_20, why does Maven 3.2.3 hang when downloading dependencies for AWS SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven-3, osx-yosemite

I am running OSX Yosemite, under JDK 1.8.0_20, with Maven 3.2.3:

```
$ sw_vers -productVersion
10.10.1
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-11T13:58:10-07:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.3
Java version: 1.8.0_20, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I have a trivial POM file that references the AWS SDK:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>innotas</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project-name</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${env.HOME}/.aws/</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If I run maven to generate the dependency tree or to build and install the project, it *always* hangs when it downloads some jar-file.  Eg:

```
$ mvn clean dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-project-name 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.9.8/aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.8.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.3.2/jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3/httpcore-4.3.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3/httpclient-4.3.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-iam/1.9.8/aws-java-sdk-iam-1.9.8.jar
224/627 KB   234/460 KB   80/276 KB   70/572 KB   64/894 KB
```

NOTE:  I have researched this topic, and people have reported similar behavior, albeit under varying circumstances (none involving Maven 3.2.3, and none involving JDK 1.8).  I tried some of these suggestions.  For example, I set:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

That did not help.  Nor did this:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m"
```

Also, I tried running maven with the NetBeans 8.x IDE; there, the bundled version is 3.0.3, I believe.  The same problem occurs:  maven hangs.

What is confounding is that I have a *much*, *much* more complicated project within the same environment, and maven works perfectly in the IDE *and* in the bash-terminal shell.

Is it possible this issue is tied to the AWS SDK plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you run `curl -O https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.9.8/aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.8.jar`?

Comment: There isn't a network issue, if that's your point.  I did try what you suggested earlier, but through the browser -- and the jar-file downloaded without a hitch.

Comment: Your browser knows about network proxies

Comment: So, I think you must be right, because I just tried the operation on my home network -- and it worked!  If you can draft a more formal answer, I'll give you credit.  Off-hand, do you know the proxy-work-around?  The issue happens at my workplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are you need some proxy settings in your ~/.m2/settings.xml file.

Have a look at [Configuring a proxy](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html).

However, a much better solution would be to use an internal Maven repository manager, such as [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/#os-arti) or  [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/nexus) which has been setup to mirror maven central with centralised proxy settings in it.

Comment: Solid answer.  Note that I did get back to work and our admin said that someone recently finagled the firewall, but that he otherwise was unaware of a proxy server for outbound HTTP requests.  We bounced our wifi modem, and it is possible that may have helped, too.  In any case, things work now.